# remove the gap between uppercase letter in math mode

Tags: spacing, equations, tex-core, letters, gap

In tex equation mode,I want 3-var MNP as a product:

```
\begin{equation*}
 N\equiv R_1\alpha NP+R_2\beta MP+R_3\gamma MN(\bmod\;MNP)
\end{equation*}
```

But the product MNP leaves obvoius spacing to each other like this:
[image]

Does someone have any good solutions?I want like this
[image]

Comment: The space helps to interpret this as a product; if you remove it, the readers might think that *MNP* is a single variable.

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap it with `\mathit`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
 N\equiv R_1\alpha NP+R_2\beta MP+R_3\gamma MN(\bmod\;MNP)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 N\equiv R_1\alpha NP+R_2\beta MP+R_3\gamma MN(\bmod\;\mathit{MNP})
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```